# Tiptap editor is overriding custom styles when I save and revisit the page?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tiptap

While interacting with the editor, my custom styles show up fine when the content is inserted.

```
    const insertSocialMediaLink = (url) => {
        if (!url) return;

        let iconUrl;
        let iconAlt;

        switch (selectedSocialMedia) {
            case 'facebook':
                iconUrl = facebookIconURL;
                iconAlt = 'Facebook';
                break;
            case 'twitter':
                iconUrl = twitterIconURL;
                iconAlt = 'Twitter';
                break;
            case 'instagram':
                iconUrl = instagramIconURL;
                iconAlt = 'Instagram';
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        editor
            .chain()
            .focus()
            .insertContent({
                type: 'linkedImage',
                attrs: {
                    src: iconUrl,
                    href: url,
                    alt: iconAlt,
                    class: styles.socialLink,
                },
            })
            .run();
        setSelectedSocialMedia(null);
    };
```

And the class is very simple:

```
.socialLink {
    background-color: black !important;
    width: 32px !important;
    height: 32px !important;
}
```

And lastly, there are a few relevant useEffects that they had set up that seem to deal with content loading/setting:

```
    const handleUpdate = ({ editor }) => {
        const html = editor.getHTML();
        // If editor is single-line or empty, remove enclosing paragraph tags
        if (singleLine || html === '<p></p>') {
            html = html.replace(/^<p>|<\/p>$/gi, '');
        }
        html = StyledParagraph.processHtml(html);

        isUpdating.current = true;
        onChange(html);
    };

    const editor = useEditor({
        extensions,
        content: value,
        onUpdate: handleUpdate,
        onBlur: ({ event }) => typeof onBlur === 'function' && onBlur(event),
        editable: !readOnly && !disabled,
        editorProps: getEditorProps(),
    });

    // Update editor settings when component props change
    useEffect(
        () => editor && editor.setOptions({ editorProps: getEditorProps() }),
        [editor, disabled, isInvalid, isValid, className, getEditorProps]
    );

    // Update editor content when value is changed externally
    // i.e. when autofilling
    useEffect(() => {
        if (editor?.commands && isUpdating.current === false) {
            editor.commands.setContent(value);
        }

        isUpdating.current = false;
    }, [editor, value]);

    if (!editor) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <div
            className={classnames(styles.editorWrapper, {
                'is-invalid': isInvalid,
                'is-valid': isValid,
            })}
        >
            <BubbleMenu editor={editor} />
            {!singleLine && editor && <FloatingMenu editor={editor} />}
            <EditorContent editor={editor} />
        </div>
    );
```

I've been unable to find out how to preserve the custom class when I load the page back up again - the editor box's socialMediaLinks revert back to no styling. I hope that wasn't too much code there, but I'm looking for direction on why TipTap is causing this to happen and if there's any workaround.